# Unable to retrieve data from Multiple collection firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hope you're in good health.
I have a problem.

```js
export function fetchListing() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(fetchListingRequest());
        //Getting Listing where status is in_review
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("listings")
            .where("status", "==", "in_review")
            .onSnapshot(
                snapshot => {
                    const data = [];
                    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                        const temp = {};
                        // Getting address of business
                        firebase
                            .firestore()
                            .collection("users")
                            .doc(doc.data().business_id)
                            .get()
                            .then(users => {
                                temp["address"] = users.data().address;
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                                dispatch(fetchListingFailed(error));
                            });
                        temp["title"] = doc.data().title;
                        temp["description"] = doc.data().description;
                        temp["listing_file"] = doc.data().listing_file;
                        data.push([doc.id, temp]);
                    });
                    dispatch(fetchListingSucess(data));
                },
                error => {
                    dispatch(fetchListingFailed(error));
                }
            );
    };
}
```

I am Unable to get address in state but when I log it It displayed in console. I am able to access address when I am retrieving it from firebase and also in reducer I am also getting address.

Answer (score 0):

reasons can be :
The hierarchy of your firestore collection
or you have to know that in js you can't affect the data to a variable that is in the main prog just when it is in a one level functions
for exemple here you can do this

```
locale = this ;
```

than you can use all the variables in two other levels